# Ruby installation in Manjaro (Arch-Based Linux)

Tags: manjaro, ruby

I was reading [the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/2021.1/set-up-a-ruby-development-environment.html#prerequisite_dependencies). In Debian based Linux, I have to install `build-essential, libssl-dev`. But, what about Arch-Based Linux? I had tried

```
sudo pacman -Syy build-essential libssl-dev
```

But, unfortunately those packages aren't available. I had tried with `yay` command also. But, I couldn't install them using `yay` also. I had installed `base-devel` also. I was reading [the question](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=122984) also. But, don't need them. PHP works by Lampp/Xampp. But, Ruby needs `build-essential && libssl-dev`. While they aren't available  in Manjaro than, how Ruby programmer works in Manjaro? So, there must be similar package like this.

- I am using Rubymine
- Ruby version : ruby 3.0.1p64 (2021-04-05 revision 0fb782ee38) [x86_64-linux]
- gem version : 3.2.15

---

I had installed `openssl` while Google is saying `build-essential` is `base-devel` and, `libssl-dev` is `openssl`.

```
sudo pacman -Sy openssl
```

Then, I had run following commands

```
gem install rails
ruby -v
gem -v 
rake -v
bundle install
```

When I tried `bundle install` I got an error `Could not locate Gemfile`.

- Bundler version : Bundler version 2.2.15

But, when I installed bundler using the command `gem install bundler` I got following error

> WARNING:  You don't have /home/istiak/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin in your PATH,
> gem executables will not run.
> Successfully installed bundler-2.2.17
> 1 gem installed

When I check rails version I get there's no `rails` package. And, I had installed rails successfully.

`gem install rails`

> WARNING:  You don't have /home/istiak/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin in your PATH,
> gem executables will not run.
> Successfully installed rails-6.1.3.2
> 1 gem installed

When I try to compile the file in Rubymine than, I get `Run Configuration Error: No Gemfile found`.

I am adding error in short below :

1. I don't have rails after installation also
2. `No Gemfile found` error while compiling ruby file from Rubymine
3. `Could not locate Gemfile` while executing `bundle install`

Comment: Arch package list https://archlinux.org/packages/

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Manjaro in a year or so but, iirc, you can use `pacman -Ss <pkgname>` (without the `<>`) to search the enabled repos for a specific package. You can also use `pkgfile <pkgname>` (without the `<>`) for a simpler list.

EDIT: after a quick Google search I found that the Arch equivalents of `build-essential` and `libssl-dev` are `base-devel` and `openssl`, respectively.

EDIT 2: if the problem is the lack of a C-compiler, you might have to install `gcc`.

EDIT 3: try these steps:

1. Close everything related to `ruby`.
2. Go to the root folder containing `Gemfile.lock` and delete it.
3. In the root folder where the file in step 2 was located, open up a terminal and run `bundle install`.
4. Open up the application after step 3 has finished, go to `Settings` > `Ruby SDK and Gems` > `Add SDK`.

EDIT 4: it looks like you haven't added the environment variable $PATH.
Add this:
`export PATH="/home/istiak/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:$PATH"`

If that doesn't work add this to your `~/.profile`:

```
export GEM_HOME="$(ruby -e 'puts Gem.user_dir')"
export PATH="$PATH:$GEM_HOME/bin"
```

Comment: I know that `base-devl` and `openssl` are package groups that will provide several other packages. They *do* provide `bison` and `autoconf`, but I am unsure if it provides the rest of the packages you mentioned. The `rubymine` package from the AUR should be precompiled and ready to use. If you don't mind me asking: are you trying to compile something and get an error? If that's the case, you will get an erroneous output and from there we can see which packages you are missing.

Comment: I don't have `rails` after running the command also `gem install rails`. I have `gem` but, I am getting error in compiler `Run configuration error : No Gemfile found`

Comment: When I tried to install bundle `bundle install` I got the error
`Could not locate Gemfile`

Comment: Please! Check I have edited my question...

Comment: Try to install `rubygems`. After you've installed `rubygems`, run `gem install bundler` - this will install `rails`.

Comment: I had installed `rubygems` using pacman. I had installed bundler again. But, rails isn't available

Comment: Sorry! actually, I am not sure where `Gemfile.lock` is located. Could you please say any possible place? In Debian, I could use `locate` command. But, it is not available in Manjaro ..

Comment: It should be in the working directory.

Comment: In my $HOME page I have Gemfile but, I don't have Gemfile.lock

Comment: Do you by any chance hide the file extensions?

Comment: I had checked using `ls -la` and `ls -a` There was only Gemfile(And, I think I had install/get it using a command few minutes ago after reading your question I had run a command from internet then, I got it. I am not sure)..

Comment: You can try to use `find` inside `~/.local/share/gem/ruby/` or `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/`.

Comment: Have you checked the [Arch wiki's Ruby page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/ruby) (it *should* work for Manjaro as well)?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in compiler I had marked the `Run the script in context of the bundle (bundle exec)`. When I unmarked it, I noticed I could compile. So, the second problem is solved

[image: compiler configuration]

Actually, in compiler I had marked the `Run the script in context of the bundle (bundle exec)`. When I unmarked it, I noticed I could compile. So, the second problem is solved. I can run Ruby file now.

[image: compiler configuration]

My gem directory was at `/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0`. I had "`Changed Directory`"

```
cd /.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0
```

Then, run following commands.

```
gem install bundler
gem install rails
bundle install
```

Comment: Ok, so that's one down. If you fire up a terminal and write `gem list` what does it say?

Comment: I have updated the answer with 'edit 3'.